# How to find the path a help-mode cross-reference points to (without visiting it)?

Tags: emacs, info

Some Emacs `*Help*` buffers include active cross-references that point to file system paths.  One can visit the associated files by following the xref in the usual way, but I want to know how to determine the path that the xref points to *without* visiting the associated file (i.e. *without* following the cross-reference).

How can I do this?

IMPORTANT: I want to to do this while *using Emacs in text-mode*.  (IOW, no mouse, no menus, etc.)

PS1: It occurs to me that one simple way to get the information I want is to view the *source code* underlying the `*Help*` buffer.  (By this I mean the mark-up that identifies the cross-referenced items, and holds their targets.)  I have not been able to find how to do this either.

PS2: Somewhere in the docs I found that running `M-x visible-mode` may display the information I'm after, but when I try it I see no additional information anywhere.  Ditto with fiddling with the variable `Info-hide-note-references`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the point in on the appropriate button:

```
(cadr (button-get (button-at (point)) 'help-args))
```

You can use this to collect all buttons:

```
(defun ali--help-collect-references ()
  "Collect the positions of visible links in the current `help-mode' buffer."
  (let ((skip (text-property-any (point-min) (point-max)
                                 'button nil))
        candidates)
    (save-excursion
      (while (setq skip (text-property-not-all skip (point-max)
                                               'button nil))
        (goto-char skip)
        (push skip candidates)
        (setq skip (text-property-any (point) (point-max)
                                      'button nil))))
    (nreverse candidates)))
```